# Finding $\int_0^7 g(r)~dr$ from $ g(r)=\begin{cases} \sqrt{9-(r-3)^2}, & 0\le r<3 \\ r+2, & 3\le r<5 \\ \sqrt{4-(r-5)^2}, & 5 \le r \le 7\end{cases} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, piecewise-continuity

I have some piece-wise integration that I for some reason am not getting.

$$
g(r) = 
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{9-(r-3)^2} && 0 \le r \lt 3 \\
r+2 && 3 \le r \lt 5 \\
\sqrt{4-(r-5)^2} && 5 \le r \le 7
\end{cases}
$$

I must find the area of $\int_0^7g(r) \ dr$.

I know that this must be equivalent to:

$$
\int_0^2\sqrt{9-(r-3)^2} \ dr \ + \ \int_3^4(r+2) \ dr \ + \ \int_5^7\sqrt{4-(r-5)^2} \ dr
$$

But my solution of $4.125 + 5.5 + \pi$ yields an incorrect answer?

Comment: Let me guess which has been your mental process: for the first segment, since $r<3$, you have to choose from 0 to 2, because 2 is the number that is prior to 3. Is that what you thought?

Comment: @projectilemotion That is the point, if this is the thought, then there is an  understanding problem about the structure of real numbers, much deeper than the particular integral problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea why you separated it like how you did it, this is incorrect:

> $$\int_0^7 g(r)~dr= \int_0^2 \sqrt{9-(r-3)^2}~dr+\int_3^4 (r+2)~dr+\int_5^7 \sqrt{4-(r-5)^2}~dr$$

Doing your method will give this area instead:

[image]

Splitting definite integrals in two does not work like when you split summations!
$$\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)\equiv \sum_{k=0}^m f(k)+\sum_{k=m+1}^n f(k)$$
$$\int_0^n f(x)~dx\not\equiv \int_0^m f(x)~dx+\int_{m+1}^n f(x)~dx$$

---

> In general, one can separate a definite integral into two definite ones as follows:
>   $$\int_a^c f(x)~dx=\int_a^b f(x)~dx+\int_b^c f(x)~dx$$

Hence, you want to separate it as follows:

$$\begin{align} \int_0^7 g(r)~dr&=\int_0^3 \sqrt{9-(r-3)^2}~dr+\int_3^5 (r+2)~dr+\int_5^7 \sqrt{4-(r-5)^2}~dr \\&=\frac{9\pi}{4}+12+\pi\\&=\frac{13\pi}{4}+12\end{align}$$
Since you managed to evaluate your other integrals, I suppose you know how to evaluate these ones to $\frac{9\pi}{4}$ and $12$, so I left it as an exercise for the reader.

---

Comment: Very good, fast and detailed answer! I wish I could upvoted 3 times for each of these reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Note: I just add this as a complement to @projectilemotion's answer.

We can still the integral into three parts as

$$\int_0^7 g(r)\; dr=\int_0^3 g(r)\; dr+\int_3^5 g(r)\; dr+\int_5^7 g(r)\; dr$$

1. For the first one, we have $y=g(r)=\sqrt{9-(r-3)^2}$, so $y^2+(r-3)^2=9$. So the region bounded by the graph of the function, the $x$-axis and the vertical lines $x=0$ and $x=3$ is a quarter of circle of center $(3,0)$ and radius. Therefore,

$$\int_0^3 g(r)\; dr=\frac{1}{4}\pi \times 3^2=\frac{9\pi}{4}$$

2. Similarly, the third integral is the area of a quarter of circle of radius $2$, so

$$\int_5^7 g(r)\; dr=\frac{1}{4}\pi \times 2^2=\pi$$

3. On $[3,5]$, the function is linear, so the region is a right trapezoid of bases $g(3)=5$ and $g(5)=7$ and height $5-3=2$, so

$$\int_3^5 g(r)\; dr=\frac{5+7}{2}\times 3=12$$

As a consequence,

$$\int_0^7 g(r)\; dr=\frac{9\pi}{4} + 12 + \pi = \frac{13\pi}{4} + 12$$